# Group by null and not null values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a Table containing facebook Ids of my users and I have to make a report on who is using facebook or not.

For the facebook user, the datarow contains a number else it contains null

My result have to be like that :

```
NbUsers   Facebook

 1000       no
  500       yes
```

I don't know how to construct my query!

Any help will be helpfull!

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: give your table structure.

Comment: Do you have any column saying its ur ID or facebook ID ,,, something like IsFacebook ? .. need to know schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it easily by case statement :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN FACEBOOKID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NbUsers , 'NO' AS FACEBOOK
FROM USERTABLE
UNION ALL 
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN FACEBOOKID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NbUsers , 'YES' AS FACEBOOK
FROM USERTABLE
```

Comment: I suggest you format your answer and put every selected column on its own row.