# SQL Server 2008 - Group by null and not null values without union

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please note the "without union" in the question title before suggesting that this is a duplicate question.

([Group by null and not null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524669/group-by-null-and-not-null-values))

For demonstration purposed:

I have a pretty large SQL that groups the results based on several criteria.
UserType, UserOrigin, LoginAttempts

e.g.

```
SELECT
    ...
GROUP BY
    UserType, UserOrigin, LoginAttempts
```

I have been able to group my results by `UserType` and `UserOrigin`.

So my results look something like this.

```
User: Admin Origin: US
User: Admin Origin: CND
User: Editor Origin: US
User: Editor Origin: UK
User: Editor Origin: MX
etc...
```

I am also trying to group the results by number of login attempts but only based on whether the value is null or not.

I don't really need information about how many time but whether the attempt ever failed.

In other words, I would like to group the results only based on whether the LoginAttempts column is not or not.

This is the desired outcome of the SQL.

```
User: Admin Origin: US Login Attempts: null
User: Admin Origin: US Login Attempts: (not null)
User: Admin Origin: CND Login Attempts: null
User: Admin Origin: CND Login Attempts: (not null)
User: Editor Origin: US Login Attempts: null
User: Editor Origin: US Login Attempts: (not null)
User: Editor Origin: UK Login Attempts: null
User: Editor Origin: UK Login Attempts: (not null)
User: Editor Origin: MX Login Attempts: null
User: Editor Origin: MX Login Attempts: (not null)


TABLE LOGINS
------------------------------
ID      LoginAttempts
1       null
2       1
3       2
4       null
5       1
6       7
```

Can anyone please help with the `GROUP BY LoginAttempt` grouping the results only by null or not null?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    UserType
    ,UserOrigin
    ,CASE WHEN LoginAttempts IS NULL
    THEN NULL
    ELSE '(not null)' END AS LoginAttempts
FROM
    ...
GROUP BY
    UserType
    ,UserOrigin
    ,CASE WHEN LoginAttempts IS NULL
    THEN NULL
    ELSE '(not null)' END
;
```